# Hibernate: get counter for insert

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

I'm using hibernate 5.2 and spring 4.3.11 on Oracle 11 RDMBS

I'm facing the following issue: I have an entity; its PK is composed by 4 columns and one of these columns is a kind of counter.
The requirement is to increment it's value of one.

So I should do something similar to this:

```
select max(counter)+1 from myTable t where t.year=2017 and t.type='test';
```

This kind of counter is neither a simple sequence. I need to be sure that the counter value (that is part of PK) is unique per client in a multi-threaded environment like the web one

So far what I wrote is:

an oracle function in order to calculate the counter
a spring transactional method with transaction isolation `SERIALIZABLE`
In my transactional method

- I call the oracle function
- I get the counter value
- I set the value to the entity
- I save the entity

I'm wondering if this is a good approach to these issue.

I can't create an oracle function or stored procedure to save the object

This is my transactional method skeleton:

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "hibTx", rollbackFor = DbException.class, readOnly = false, isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void saveMyEntity(Entity t) throws DbException{
    try
    {
        EntityPK id = t.getId();
        //Oracle DAO is a DAO where I have method to call oracle functions and stored
        Long nextCounter = oracleDao.getNextValue( id.getYear(), id.getType(), t.getCode().longValue() ).longValue();
        id.setCounter(nextCounter);
        t.setId(id);
        repository.persist(t);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        String msg = "Error; "+e.getMessage();
        logger.error(msg, e);
        throw new DbException(msg);
    }   
}
```

Any suggestion is welcome

Thank you

Angelo

Comment: hi,  why can't  you use sequence.nextval as this e.g  INSERT INTO someTable( list_of_columns ) 
  VALUES( my_sequence.nextval, list_of_other_columns );

Comment: I need a unique value based on year and type. Sequence is always unique. For example year is 2017. I can have value 1 both for type 'test' and for type 'rest'. By using sequence i'll have value 1 for 'test' and value 2 for 'rest'.

Comment: you want always number? how about concrete seq with yr & type . my_sequence.nextval_yyyy_type  ==> 1234_2017_test

Comment: I thought about this solution but sadly it's always a number and I can't modify it